# Destiny Number Calculator

Tags: c++

hi can someone please help me to complete this code in c++ if you may interested

here is the project which will print the position of a char in string, this is very close to my task but not exactly

here is the problem: program only print the position of a char, for example for letter 'S' it prints 18 because it sits at position 18, how i can change this program which instead of that, the program print my values, i don't really care about the position i care about the value that should return or store, the value i specify,

program for sam prints

S=18

A=1

M=13

instead i want it know for letter S print 7 or store 7, i mean instead of caring about position should care about the value at the final result which i explained

all 26 alphabet as you see has a value base on the position i want that pos value to be changed and result other pos int value

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<exception>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const std::string alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    cout << "Please enter your the name:";
    std::string text;
    std::cin >> text;

    // convert all lower case characters to upper case
    for (char& c : text)
        c = std::toupper(c);

    // Lookup character
    for (char& c : text) // for each character c in text
    {
        const auto pos = alpha.find(c);

        if (pos != std::string::npos) // if found (if the character is an alpha character)
                                      // note: non-alpha characters are ignored
        {
            const int value = pos + 1; // +1 because position of 'A' is 0, value of 'A' is 1
            // Print the character and the position
            cout << c << "=" << pos << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you having troubles?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of result you're looking for. If you're looking to return values in the range of the alphabet, then just rearrange the letters to match what you want them to return.

If you're looking for something with higher or lower values, then take a look at building a map and accessing the key value pairs. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: thank you very much, i am an IT student and it was my first post in stackoverflow, i will dig in <map> hopefully i can find the solution

Comment: i thought also about rearrenging the alphabet but some aphabets are going to have same value can that happen? like i group ABC and it return 1, i mean all three of them in position 1, thx

Comment: can i use something like bubble sort with a for loop to relocate position?